# Are there any American minhagim?

Tags: minhag, history, halacha-theory, jewish-american-history

I am curious about the nature of American [minhagim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minhag)/customs.

Are there any minhagim that are specifically of American origin, and what are their qualifications? Most people receive their minhagim from either their [ancestors or teachers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish_culture), both of whom originated from anywhere in Europe or the Middle East, Poland, Africa & Russia or anywhere else. Standard minhagim for communities are today established by Rabbis and authorities who, themselves, have lineage or authority in transmitting their origin's minhagim, and base the minhag on their collective national minhag of old.

Are there any contemporary standards today which, in a broad historical sense, would be deemed "minhag" in binding terms - and based on what definition?

For example:

- certain [norms of dress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haredi_Judaism#Dress) which are highly enforced today, as oppose to the previous generations' lack of obsession with codes of dress.
- Or even [social stringencies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kollel#Community_kollelim) in regards to learning in kollel and various chumrot which are adopted by tens of thousands of Bnei Yisrael.
- In present terms, do the thousands of Jews who [recite Hallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_Day_(Israel)#Religious_customs) with or without a beracha on Yom HaAzma'ut create a level of minhag upon themselves by doing so?

Do these qualify as minhagei America? I am not asking about these particular cases, rather using them as expressions of the underlying question. An answer to this question would include objective standards used to qualify some adherence as a minhag or minhag hamakom, and an example of some custom which qualifies as such.

Comment: I think that the Jews that recite Hallel on Yom Haatzmaut is not a minhagei America because there is a Machlokes about whether you say so or not.

Comment: @Josh Would they be minhagei New York, or even minhagim of a particular community or kehilla?

Comment: They would be the minhagim of the specific shul or school or community

Comment: The practice of eating only _glatt_ meat certainly didn't originate in America but it is widely practiced in the United States and AFAIK far more prevalently than in other countries.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%94%D7%92+%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%94&oq=%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%94%D7%92+%D7%90%D7%9E&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.26113j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=%22%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%94%D7%92+%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%94%22

Comment: Many Jews in U.S. (perhaps, this is more of a large city, minhag) have a minhag to go to a movie or play followed by eating Chinese food on Christmas. Also, many American Jews eat turkey on Thanksgiving.

Comment: This question seems to broad as it asks five questions: 1) What are the standards to qualify something as a minhag or minhag hamakom? 2) Do these qualify as minhagei America (Itself three questions, for three examples)? and 3) Are there any minhagim that are specifically of American origin?

Comment: @mevaqesh I've edited to try to unify the question.

Comment: It seems improved but I think it still constitutes two questions: 1) the definition of an authoritative minhag, 2) an example of one from America.

Comment: If there is a particular wording for the prayer for the government near universally used in orthodox congregations might that become a national (for want of a better word) minhag?

Comment: http://www.torahmusings.com/2017/03/minhag-america-american-nationalism/

Comment: http://revach.net/halacha/daily-halacha/Getting-Dressed-Rav-Moshe-Feinstein-On-The-American-Wardrobe/3882

Comment: While I can't say there is a broad American minhag yet, we can see one emerging. E.g. every time a Litvisher or Yekkish friend of mine invites me to an Upsherin. Tefillin on chol hamo'ed is slowly becoming more and more rare. These things take time, but I think we can see the process in motion. I expect, though, that the relocation to our ancestral lands by sheivet and clan will break the current process before a Minhag America emerges in full.

Comment: Can't answer because it's closed, and I don't have sources. I was told that the minhag in America is to take out shabbos at [8.5°](https://www.myzmanim.com/read/degrees.aspx). Also, before WWII the minhag was to turn on lights on the second day of yom tov.

Comment: @ploni I would love to see a source for that second minhag. Was that minhag, or did someone actually pasken that way?

Comment: @Chaim See [here](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/english/journal/broyde_1.htm) under the title "III. Electricity and Lights on Yom Tov".

Comment: Sarah Palin sheitels. Nusach Ashkenaz?

Answer (score 2):

Congregations have their own minhagim that may not necessarily be those of their previous countries. I don't think that there are are minhagei America but there are definitely minhagim of a specific shul.

Comment: We certainly have the opposite. When I lived in Washington Heights, NYC, there was a *Yekke* shul (besides the famous Breuer's, which still exists) that firmly followed all the *Yekke* minhagim and nuscha'ot. All the congregants were American born.