# Minhag Hamakom in America according to R' Moshe Feinstein

Tags: halacha, minhag, halacha-theory, moshe-feinstein, united-states

1. I've heard that R' Moshe Feinstein said there's no Minhag Hamakom (Minhag of the area/Community) in America. Where can I find this?
2. Is he saying that there is no one "unified" Minhag Hamakom that holds for the whole country or there are no Minhagey Hamakom anywhere in the USA even in places like New Square and Kiryas Yoel?

Comment: Similar https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/82289/759

Comment: What does *Daas Yehudit* mean in the context of this question? Is that the name of a minhag?

Comment: @DanF Ive edited it in a brief explanation of Daas Yehudit. Some examples in the gemara seem to be not spinning in the market place and fully covering their hair in the marketplace(Instead of just a basket).

Comment: It's Dat not Daat

Comment: @DoubleAA In these instances I find it most helpful to add the Hebrew so the person gets the difference; Dat (דת) not Daat (דעת).

Comment: Minhag Hamakom refers to any defined area that has only one Beis Din. Once there are more than one BDs in the same area (see anywhere in the USA), there's no one obligating MH as everyone can say - "I'm subordinate to a different BD". Same in Israel and even Jerusalem and even Meah Shearim.